# Permissions error upon running Add-DistributionGroupMember PS cmdlet on Exchange Online

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, exchange-server

I'm currently trying to automate the user creation in Azure AD, and addition to a distribution group in Exchange Online using a PowerShell script. I've followed [this](https://adamtheautomator.com/exchange-online-powershell-mfa/#Creating_an_Azure_AD_Application_with_API_Permissions) guide for that - I've set up an app registration with a certificate and that's how I'm authenticating to both Azure AD and Exchange Online - without human intervention.

The specific Exchange cmdlet I'm running in the script (for the EXO part) is `Add-DistributionGroupMember -member "user@domain.com" -identity "dlist" -BypassSecurityGroupManagerCheck`, and once I run it I receive the following error output:

```
Active Directory operation failed on XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXXX.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM. This error is not retriable. Additional information: Insufficient access rights to perform the operation.
Active directory response: 00002098: SecErr: DSID-XXXXXXXX, problem 4003 (INSUFF_ACCESS_RIGHTS), data 0
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-DistributionGroupMember], ADOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : [Server=XXXXXXXXXXXXX,RequestId=8ac3130a-4bbe-41a0-b062-4768b6f51234,TimeStamp=1/3/2021 2:18:13 PM] [FailureCategory=Cmdlet-ADOperationException] XXXXXXX,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.AddDistribu
   tionGroupMember
    + PSComputerName        : outlook.office365.com
```

Other cmdlets such as
`Get-Mailbox` work correctly, but this specific one is giving me problems constantly. I've tried giving all API permissions I can think of in Azure to the application, both Delegated and Application permissions, and yet I'm still facing the error. Here's the current full list and I've had no success whatsoever:

[image]

I also tried replacing some of the Delegated permissions with Application permissions to no avail either.  I tried assigning a variety of roles to the application as mentioned in the [article](https://adamtheautomator.com/exchange-online-powershell-mfa/#Creating_an_Azure_AD_Application_with_API_Permissions) too and every single time I get that `Insufficient access rights to perform the operation` error.

Could someone tell me why? Where and how am I supposed to grant the necessary permissions for the app to add a user to a distribution (mailing) list?

I've been searching around and found no answer to it for that last few days. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: hi, Josh have you solved this problem finally, I also met this problem and can not solve it.

Comment: I am also wondering if you resolved this issue Josh. Getting a similar error when attempting to create a mailbox "New-Mailbox" We are also using a cert to run some automation scripts in Exchange. The interesting thing is that using the same cert, I can create a mailbox from my PC yet it errors from the server. The server is in the same domain.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my test, adding `Exchange.ManageAsApp` Application permission and assigning **Exchange Service administrator** role is enough.

Create the AAD app with adding `Exchange.ManageAsApp` Application permission.

```
$appName = 'Exo_V2_App'

$api = (Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "AppID eq '00000002-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000'")

$permission = $api.AppRoles | Where-Object { $_.Value -eq 'Exchange.ManageAsApp' }

$apiPermission = [Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RequiredResourceAccess]@{
    ResourceAppId  = $api.AppId ;
    ResourceAccess = [Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess]@{
        Id   = $permission.Id ;
        Type = "Role"
    }
}

$myApp = New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName $appName -ReplyUrls 'http://localhost' -RequiredResourceAccess $apiPermission

$mySP = New-AzureADServicePrincipal -AppID $myApp.AppID

$myApp | Format-List DisplayName,ObjectID,AppID
```

Assign the service principal to **Exchange Service administrator** role.

```
$directoryRole = 'Exchange Service Administrator'

$RoleId = (Get-AzureADDirectoryRole | Where-Object {$_.displayname -eq $directoryRole}).ObjectID

Add-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember -ObjectId $RoleId -RefObjectId $mySP.ObjectID -Verbose
```

You can try to create a new clean Azure AD app without adding additional configuration to have a test.

Comment: Anecdotal, but I have an Azure AD app with Exchange.ManageAsApp and Exchange Service administrator role, and `Add-DistributionGroupMember` fails with strange errors like `Source server:DM6PR19MB3113.namprd19.prod.outlook.com doesn't have write permission to target DC:BN6PR04A05DC004.NAMPR04A005.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM. Usually it indicates that target forest isn't an account partition of source forest. Additional information: Insufficient access rights to perform the operation.`

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, you should be part of the **ManagedBy** of the group before adding the members.

**Step 1 :**

First execute one of the below commands :

```
Set-DistributionGroup <NameOfGroup> -ManagedBy "<Your Alias>" -BypassSecurityGroupManagerCheck
```

Or :

```
Set-DistributionGroup Accounting -ManagedBy @{Add="< Your Alias>"} -BypassSecurityGroupManagerCheck
```

**Step 2 :**

Then execute the command to add the user to the group.

```
Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity <NameOfGroup> -Member user@contoso.com
```

Answer (score 0):

We had a very similar issue that was resolved by updating the Exchange Online PowerShell module version from 2.0.5 to 3.1.0.

Command to check version:

```
Get-InstalledModule ExchangeOnlineManagement | Format-List Name,Version,InstalledLocation
```

Command to update to latest version:

```
Update-Module -Name ExchangeOnlineManagement
```